# Configure Validation data on deep learning

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, deep-learning, neural-network

I am a little confused about the best way to use validation data on deep learning model. I have read the documentation and other similar questions but still not clear.

I am testing 3 different procedures

first:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True, stratify=y)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y_train)

# Training the model and saving the history
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150,
                    batch_size=128, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Second:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True, stratify=y)

# Training the model and saving the history
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150,
                    batch_size=128, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Third:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True, stratify=y)

# Training the model and saving the history
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150,
                    batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

From my understanding both the first and third approaches are right while the second one is wrong as the same X_test, y_test will also be used for testing

Can you please suggest which of the three procedures is right?

Comment: For what it's worth, I always use the first method and `evaluate` on `X_test` and `y_test`.

Comment: perhaps yes. After running the experiments for 10times I notice that with the third procedure the overall results are better, however, the overfitting is notable. Not much but it is there

Comment: That's why I prefer the first approach to avoid overfitting

Comment: However, the reason behind this is not easily understood. The documentation states that the 0.2 are directly taken from the train data. So why the overfitting occurs?

Comment: You are right for the [validation_split](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#automatically_setting_apart_a_validation_holdout_set). I can't explain the overfitting (maybe the random_state?). You don't control the seed in fit.